# CSS: Make Child Flexbox expand to Width of Its Parent Flexbox

Tags: css, sass

How do I make a Child flexbox expand/stretch to the Width of its Large Parent Flexbox?

Width 100% of child element is not working in the css.

Comment: try setting `flex:1` on the child element

Comment: please write as answer, and I can send points, thanks @AndreiVoicu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`flex: 1` means the following:

- flex-grow : 1;    ➜ The div will grow in same proportion as the window-size
- flex-shrink : 1;  ➜ The div will shrink in same proportion as the window-size
- flex-basis : 0;   ➜ The div does not have a starting value as such and will
  take up screen as per the screen size available for
  e.g:- if 3 divs are in the wrapper then each div will take 33%.

```css
.parent{
    display: flex;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid lime;
}

.child {
    flex: 1;
    border: 1px solid hotpink;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```